# How to change quiz word to test in moodle

Tags: moodle

I'm using moodle version 2.8 with evolve theme. The requirement is to replace "quiz" word with "test" word everywhere in moodle.

Please help me out in this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to look in the Language Customisation.

Home > Administration block > Site administration > Language > Language customisation

Choose language, select "Open for editing" ("Continue").  Highlight all components (shift-select) in the list, and then search for your "quiz" string using the "Only strings containing" field.

Note that this will give you every single instance, and that will include things like "the course does not contain any quiz activities" and so on.

The names of the strings are **usually** indicative of whether the text will present to an average user or to only admins/managers - for instance the above text is "config_no_quizzes_in_course" and that would suggest that it only displays when configuring the quiz results block.   You may choose not to change all of the instances of the word quiz, and only those ones which will be user-facing.